# Variable rnn/gru_cell/gates/weights already exists, disallowed

Tags: tensorflow

I want to implement the code in th book Tesorflow for Machine Intelligence, the code runs well at the first time,but when run it again ,the error 
"Variable rnn/gru_cell/gates/weights already exists, disallowed" occurs. when I restart the console the error disapear and it occurs after the first running or debug. the code is below:

```
def prediction(self):

    output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(300), 
                                  self.data, 
                                  dtype = tf.float32,
                                  sequence_length = self.length)
    last = self._last_relevant(output, self.length)
    #softmax层
    num_classes  =int(self.target.get_shape()[1])
    weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([self.params.rnn_hidden, num_classes], stddev = 0.01))
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape = [num_classes]))
    prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias)
    return prediction
```

anyone can help me with the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Code that adds things to your graph (which includes pretty much everything in the function you posted) should usually only be run once.  When you want to train your model or have it make a prediction, you would use something like `sess.run` with a `feed_dict` and the ops you want output from.

If you actually want to delete your graph without restarting the console, you can use `tf.reset_default_graph()`.